# Reusing NSObjects by Overriding release in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, overriding, release, reusability, nsobject

I am implementing an object reuse scheme using a singleton class.

What I do basically is:

```
MyClass* obj = [[MyClassBank sharedBank] getReusableItem];
```

The bank is just an NSMutableSet tweaked for optimum reusability. When I was happily implementing this Singleton, I had in mind that I will just do the following when I am done with "obj":

```
[[MyClassBank sharedBank] doneWithItem:obj];
```

Currently, My code would work if I where to use it this way, but I later realized that I sometimes add "obj" to an "NSCollection", and sometimes I call:

```
[theCollection removeAllObjects];
```

At first I thought about making my own class that is composed of a collection, then I would iterate the objects within the collection and call:

```
[[MyClassBank sharedBank] doneWithItem:obj];
```

But, that's too much of a hassle, isn't?

A neat idea (I think) popped into my mind, which is to override: `-(oneway void)release;`, so, I immediately jumped to Apple's documentation, but got stuck with the following:

> You would only implement this method to define your own reference-counting scheme. Such implementations should not invoke the inherited method; that is, they should not include a release message to super.

Ao, I was reluctant to do that idea .. basically:

```
-(oneway void)release{
    if ([self retainCount] == 1) {
        //This will increment retain count by adding self to the collection.
        [[MyClassBank sharedBank] doneWithItem:self];
    }
    [super release];
}
```

Is it safe to do that?

PS: Sorry for the long post, I want the whole idea to be clear..

**EDIT:**

<strike>How about overriding `alloc` alltogther and adding `[[MyClassBank sharedBank] getReusableItem];` there?</strike>

Comment: This is my first time knowing about the object pool pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Suggested method:

You're playing with the reference counting system.  99.9999999999999999% of the time this is a bad idea.  I would highly recommend going with a different mechanism.  Perhaps these objects could implement their own reference count that's independent of the `retainCount`?  Then you could use that referenceCount to actually control when an object is ready to be re-used or not.

### Not suggested method:

If, for some weird reason, you can't do that, then you could do the following thing **that is still a bad idea and that i don't recommend you actually use**:

You can override `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [ivar release], ivar = nil;
  [anotherIvar release], anotherIvar = nil;
  somePrimitive = 0;
  // do not call [super dealloc]
}

- (void)_reallyDealloc {
  [self dealloc];  // clean up any ivars declared at this level
  [super dealloc]; // then continue on up the chain
}
```

Basically, the `dealloc` method would be the point at which the object is ready for re-use.  When you're totally done with the object and finally want it to go away, you can use the `_reallyDealloc` method to continue on up the chain, eventually resulting in the object getting freed.

**PLEASE** don't do this.  With things like Automatic Reference Counting, this is going to introduce you into a world of hurt and really bizarre debugging scenarios.  A *lot* of the tools and classes and stuff depend on the reference counting mechanism to be working without alteration, so screwing around with it is usually not a Good Idea™.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say. My only addendum, a possible "not really suggested" third method: If you absolutely _must_ use your own memory management model and feel like you have to override `-release`, you might consider using key-value observing on the `retainCount` property. I would guess that objects could observe their own `retainCount`. This way, at least, you don't mess with the implementation of methods like `release`.

Comment: Sorry, but I either didn't fully understand your recommended way of implementing my own reference count, or you didn't notice that my problem is when an NSArray calls release on the object :) .. The only way is to override release OR dealloc, as you stated. But you won't recommend any?

Comment: @Mazyod if you have to do it, it's marginally safer to do it via the `dealloc` method than the `release` method, especially since the new ARC feature bypasses `release` entirely to go with a lower-level runtime function.

Comment: btw, I'll be calling [super dealloc] directly, this way, from calling _reallyDealloc :S .. Isn't this VERY bad??

Comment: I would strongly, _strongly_ suggest creating and using an `ObjectPool` class, maybe with a `prototype` object implementing the `NSCopying` protocol that gets copied on demand. Overriding `release` or `dealloc` violates the principle of least surprise and works against Cocoa's grain.

Comment: Another option: You might consider a category on the collection classes in question with a method like `-returnToBank`. That way you can use an idiom like `removeAllObjects` without needing to worry about this kind of `retain`/`release` devilry.

Comment: +1 for categories ... Damn, I always forget how awesome they are :D. Thanks a lot, Joe!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>For ppl who find this approach interesting/useful, Here is a cleaner way than calling `[super dealloc];` directly (which is definitely bad)</strike>

```
//BAD!
//-(void)dealloc{
//  for some reason, the retainCount at this point == 1
//  if (![[BankStep sharedBank] purgeFlag]) {
//      [self resetObject];
//      [[BankStep sharedBank] doneWithItem:self];
//  } else {
//      [children release];
//      [super dealloc];
//  }
//}
```

by calling `[[Bank sharedBank] purgeBank];` , set the flag to true, then remove all objects from the NSSet.

Adapted solution:

@Joe Osborn idea of using categories to implement a `returnToBank` Method!

Comment: Anyone interested to know what happened to me, read: I wanted to use two objects that are instances of custom classes. One was straight forward using [pool getReusableObject]; then [object returnToPool]; .. The other one, however, was a PITA. I spent two days trying to model it, since the object has a pointer to a parent and an array of children from the same class, not to mention it existed in arrays and ivars all over the place ... yeah, a PITA .. It took me exactly 5 minutes to implement the striked out answer posted above, and the NSlogs shows its working perfectly ......